# Tkinter is not displaying the window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am creating a simple text window using tkinter in pycharm, but it always shows me attribute error. When I use "python3 -m tkinter" in terminal its working fine, but when it comes to pycharm its not working. I am sharing my code below as well as the error I got.

==>CODE<==

```
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()

window.title("GUI")

label = tkinter.Label(window, text="Welcome to Tkinter!").pack()

window.mainloop()
```

==>ERROR<==

```
/usr/bin/python3.6 "/home/PycharmProjects/Practice Projects/intro.py"
 
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/PycharmProjects/Practice Projects/intro.py", line 3, in <module>

window = tkinter.Tk()

AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Tk'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: My guess is you have someother file in your directory with name `tkinter.py`, you will have to rename it to something else, as python confuses it to be the tkinter your trying to import.

Comment: Unrelated, but `label = tkinter.Label(window, text="Welcome to Tkinter!").pack()` makes `label` the result of `pack()`, i.e. `None`, not the actual `Label`.

Comment: I checked my python directory there is not a single file named tkinter.py. Is it corrupted or something else?

Comment: Not pythons directory, you should check the directory with `intro.py`

Answer (score -1):

Try `import tkinter as tk` instead of `import tkinter`. Or you can import tkinter such as `from tkinter import *`.

Usage:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

window.title("GUI")

label = tk.Label(window, text="Welcome to Tkinter!")
label.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

or

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

window.title("GUI")

label = Label(window, text="Welcome to Tkinter!")
label.pack()

window.mainloop()
```